# Solr: Can we enable stop-words on query time?

Tags: solr

Can we enable stop-words on query time? like to enable highlighting or grouping we have to enable that feature first. Or stop-words can only be define on a field in a schema?

Comment: why one would need to enable stopwords in query time?

Comment: @Mysterion I think it is good to provide additional feature to stop-word on/off at query time. Queries has different context, so suppose we analyzed some text before querying and found that the stopwords would be required for retrieving the more relevant results then it could be helpful.

Comment: @MTA As per my knowledge, currently Solr is not providing the on/off stopword feature in query time.